# How can I fix my code not finding keywords in a list?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, lxml

I've got the code beneath. I need it to extract the names of products from a html page which it does just fine. Then, I need it to match the input to an element in the list and output the index of it. Even though there are elements such as 'Liquid Tee' and the input is 'liquid', it doesn't match them.

If you have any idea why, I'd be more than thankful!

Here is the code sample:

```
import urllib3
from bs4 import beautifulsoup
from lxml import etree

url = https://www.example.com    
response = http.request('GET', url)    
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.data)    
keyword = input()    
data = etree.HTML(str(soup))    
all_names = data.xpath('//a[@class="name-link"]/text()')    
namenumbered = [i for i, s in enumerate(all_names) if keyword in s]
```

Comment: Strings in Python are case sensitive, so `'Liquid'` will not match `'liquid'`. As for getting the index of list elements, you can try `idx = my_list.index('my_string')`. `index` will throw an error if `my_string` is not in `my_list`.

Comment: @WolfgangK thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like stated above, it's case sensitive. If you want `liquid` to be found in `Liquid Tee`, you could use regex, or just make it all caps/all lowercase when you check if the keyword is present in the string:

```
all_names = ['liquid!', 'Liquid Tee', 'LIQUID', 'liguid ', 'hello', 'The water is LiQuId.']

keyword = 'liquid'

namenumbered = [i for i, s in enumerate(all_names) if keyword.lower() in s.lower()]
```

**Outputs:**

correctly outputs liquid found at index/position 0, 1, 2, and 5

```
print (namenumbered)
[0, 1, 2, 5]
```

But without change to lower, will only identify position [0].

```
all_names = ['liquid!', 'Liquid Tee', 'LIQUID', 'liguid ', 'hello', 'The water is LiQuId.']

keyword = 'liquid'


namenumbered = [i for i, s in enumerate(all_names) if keyword in s]
```

**Output:**

```
print (namenumbered)
[0]
```